# nodejs child_process: write stdout in realtime & run sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

Info
node: v9.4.0

I would like to run external commands sequentially, but see stdout in realtime.

I wrote an example below. This is for getting all test cases in `./test/` and then run one by one. In this example, stdout is written in realtime, but all test cases are run at the same time, which is a problem.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const fs = require('fs');
let test;

fs.readdirSync('./test/').forEach(file => {
    test = spawn('npm', ['test', 'test/' + file]);

    test.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`${data}`);
    }); 

    test.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`${data}`);
    }); 

    test.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`code: ${code}`);
    }); 
});
```

Could you tell me how to achieve these two things at once?
- Run all test cases one by one
- Write stdout in realtime

(Someone may think why I have to run tests one by one. This is because those test cases require me to use a remote server which cannot deal well with parallel tasks. The server is not under my control, so I am trying to manage this in node js script.)

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: The version is v9.4.0. I added this info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simulate something like a mutex lock (for async operations) using promises in JS and lock **before** spawning each process and unlock when the process ends:

```
class Mutex {
  constructor() {
    this._queue = [];
  }

  lock() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const allow = () => {
        resolve(this._unlock.bind(this));
      };
      this._queue.push(allow);
      if (this._queue.length === 1) {
        allow();
      }
    });
  }

  _unlock() {
    this._queue.shift();
    const next = this._queue[0];
    if (typeof next === 'function') {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const fs = require('fs');
let test;

const mutex = new Mutex();

fs.readdirSync('./test/').forEach(async file => {
    const unlock = await mutex.lock();

    test = spawn('npm', ['test', 'test/' + file]);

    test.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`${data}`);
    }); 

    test.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`${data}`);
    }); 

    test.on('close', (code) => {
        unlock();
        console.log(`code: ${code}`);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Code didnt work exactly as is.  Node didnt recognize that Mutex class.  Concept is sold though.  After npm installing async-mutex and making a few adjustments to work with that module, it worked nicely.